# Amazon EC2 3306 timeout

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to connect to MySQL on a EC2 instance. Not RDS.

## Security Group

### Inbount

```
TCP (6) 9090 aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/32 Openfire / Admin Con...
TCP (6) 5222 0.0.0.0/0          Openfire / Client to...
TCP (6) 3306 0.0.0.0/0
```

### Outbound

Relevant?

## EC2

```
$ netstat -nat | grep 3306
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          aa.bb.cc.dd:59134       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          aa.bb.cc.dd:59142       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          aa.bb.cc.dd:59140       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          aa.bb.cc.dd:59136       ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          aa.bb.cc.dd:59138       ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:59138         127.0.0.1:3306          ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:59136         127.0.0.1:3306          ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:59134         127.0.0.1:3306          ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:59140         127.0.0.1:3306          ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:59142         127.0.0.1:3306          ESTABLISHED

$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive

$ netstat -nat | grep 9090
tcp6       0      0 :::9090                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

## With my localhost

```
% nc -zv aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd 8080
nc: connectx to aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd port 8080 (tcp) failed: Connection refused

% nc -zv aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd 9090
found 0 associations
found 1 connections:
     1: flags=82<CONNECTED,PREFERRED>
    outif en7
    src aa.bb.cc.dd port 65511
    dst ee.ff.gg.hh port 9090
    rank info not available
    TCP aux info available

Connection to aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd port 9090 [tcp/websm] succeeded!

% nc -zv aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd 5222
found 0 associations
found 1 connections:
     1: flags=82<CONNECTED,PREFERRED>
    outif en7
    src aa.bb.cc.dd port 65512
    dst ee.ff.gg.hh port 5222
    rank info not available
    TCP aux info available

Connection to aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd port 5222 [tcp/jabber-client] succeeded!

% nc -zv aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd 3306
nc: connectx to aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd port 3306 (tcp) failed: Operation timed out
```

Why 3306 time outs only?

Comment: Can you do a netstat for 9090 for comparison? Please edit your question rather than adding it to comments.

Comment: @Tim As you wish.

Comment: Puzzling. Looks fine. I'm not familiar with nc. What happens if you try to connect with the command line mysql client? Have you checked iptables, or is there some other firewall technology in place?

Comment: @Tim Thank you for your help. I couldn't help myself but changed the port number other than `3306`.

Answer (score -1):

This is actually not an answer but an workaround.

It seems that AWS blocks `3306`.
I don't know what other configuration such as ACL.

I changed the port to `3307` and added a rule for that.
Then it simply connects.

Comment: Should I've used `a`, not `an`, before *workaround*?

Comment: This is incorrect. AWS does not block port 3306 or any other port, it's entirely under your control. I have in the past connected to MySQL on RDS over 3306, and yesterday I connected to MySQL on my EC2 server on port 3306. You have either an error in your MySQL configuration or you haven't set up a firewall properly - iptables, security groups, network ACLs.

Comment: @Tim ACL is the only thing that I haven't checked. It is possibly the reason?

Comment: Yes, that's one possibility, but if you haven't changed them then it's not that. NACLs are open by default. Most likely is you've configured something else incorrectly. If you really wanted a solution you could pay a professional to log in and work it out for you, but if you're happy using a different port then do that if you like. I can say that AWS **definitely** does not block port 3306 as I access resources in AWS over 3306.

Comment: @Tim Thank you for your comment. I'll update on any changes.